# Probit Model: Interpretation of marginal effects if explanatory variables are proportions

Tags: estimation, interpretation, proportion, probit, marginal-effect

How do I interpret the marginal effect of an explanatory variable that is a proportion in a probit model? For example if I get a marginal effect of 0.8 does this mean that if the proportion  increases by 1 percent the response probability increases ceteris paribus by 0.8 percent?

Comment: I believe that's right. An increase in X by 1 unit (the unit depends on the scale you are using, in this case it is therefore 1%), increases Y by 0.8%

Comment: Thanks. Both in percentage points, right? a 1 perecentage point increase in X leads to a 0.8 percentage point increase in Y

Comment: Did you get the question right? I am not asking about interpretation of the parameters but of the marginal effects? For example AMEs.

Comment: @Peter that's correct.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the original question, @Fuca26 is entirely correct.  It is important to note that the marginal effect is a linearization, and only meaningful around the current parameter value.